# How can I emulate ajaxStart and ajaxStop without jQuery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been looking at the jQuery code but is kinda huge. Would this be an easy task? Any idea how to do it?

The reason I want to do this is because I want to use it not for a web page but for a C# application that needs to know when there is ajax activity going on in a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx). So I would inject my javascript code in any web page I want to detect ajax activity, instead of injecting the whole jQuery which might be already present and cause a conflict.

Comment: You might also just want to check whether jQuery is already present and not inject it if so.

Comment: How would you check that? And what if it has a modified version of jQuery. I can do that but it wouldn't be as safe as the way I want to do it.

Comment: Something like `jQuery().jquery` would return the version number. However, you are correct that it might not be the safest solution so please ignore it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's `ajaxStart` doesn't fire for arbitrary `XMLHttpRequest` events, only for those coming from within jQuery.

You can trivially test* this by spinning up your own `XMLHttpRequest` after registering an `ajaxStart` handler.

So, technically, its easy to emulate: just route all your ajax traffic through a common method.

I doubt that's going to help you much since you won't actually capture *all* ajax requests, just the ones you kick off (and thus already know about, by definition).

<sub>*I did, since I wasn't sure.</sub>