# How to keep track of ongoing ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am executing simultaneous ajax request on a button click.

I have a table with a list of alarms and each row has it's own button that once clicked tries to clear the alarm in the db and then I remove it from the table.

I can click on these buttons one after another and trigger an ajax request.

**Problem**:

lets say I click on a button and for some reason this is taking time and the user manages to click on yet another button to start a new ajax.

I want to execute a script block in my ajax succes method **ONLY** if all the ajax requests in the current scope are finished.

code:

```
$(".signAlarm")
    .on("click",
        function () {
            var _this = $(this).parents(".alarmRow");
            var alarm = {
                Id: $(_this).data("id")
            }
            $.automation.worker.postJson("/Alarm/SigAlarm",
            JSON.stringify({ alarm }),
            function (data) {
                if (!$.automation.worker.ajaxActive()) {
                    // execute this if all the sign alarm attempts are finished                               
                }
                $(_this).remove();
            });
        });
```

ajaxActive function:

```
ajaxActive: function() {
    if ($.active) return true;

    return false;
}
```

when searching for an answer I found [jquery.active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148225/jquery-active-function) which I use in the attempt above but when I check the jquery.active in my success method it is "1" and not 0 even though only one button click has been made.

I also checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822913/how-do-i-know-if-jquery-has-an-ajax-request-pending) which got me thinking of jquery.active above but alos $.ajaxStart and $.ajaxStopp.

The problem with $.ajaxStart and $.ajaxStopp and far as I understand is that they are global and I want specific code to execute when these alarms are signed and don't wish for this to happen on every page when an ajax is made.

How do I manage this?

Comment: you want to track the AJAX calls or you want execute some code only after the list of calls are completed??

Comment: i want to execute script when all ajax are cmpleated in this scope. With that in mind these request are not dependent on eacother.  i simply want to know if the browser is running any ajax requests when I come back to my success method. If there are ajax request still running (user clicked on yet another button) then do nothing, else execute script

Comment: related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5680537/470749

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a great deal of pondering and searching for some kind of build in function in jquery i decided to make an own attempt.

What I wanted:

1. Make several ajax requests
2. Keep track of the amount of request that I had in a particular scope(NOT GLOBAL)
3. execute script when no ajax are being made.

code:

global array:

```
 ajaxRequests: { value: [] }
```

before each ajax request:

```
$.automation.globals.ajaxRequests.value.push(1);
```

after each ajax request:

```
    clearAjax: function() {
        $.automation.globals.ajaxRequests.value.splice(-1, 1);
    }
```

summing it up:

```
       $(".signAlarm")
            .on("click",
                function () {
                    var _this = $(this).parents(".alarmRow");
                    var alarm = {
                        Id: $(_this).data("id")
                    }

                    $.automation.globals.ajaxRequests.value.push(1);

                    $.automation.worker.postJson("/Alarm/SigAlarm",
                    JSON.stringify({ alarm }),
                    function (data) {
                        $.automation.worker.clearAjax();
                        if ($.automation.globals.ajaxRequests.value.length === 0) {
                           // all ajax finished, execute code
                        }
                        $(_this).remove();
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [deferred objects](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

```
$('.signAlarm').each(function() {
    var prom = $.Deferred().resolve();
    $(this).click(function() {
        var _this = $(this).parents(".alarmRow");
        var alarm = {
            Id: $(_this).data("id")
        };
        prom = prom.then(
            function () {
                return $.post({
                    'url': '/Alarm/SigAlarm',
                    'data': JSON.stringify(alarm),
                    'contentType': 'application/json' // assuming you want the server to think you're sending json
                });
            }
        ).done(function () {
            if (prom.state() === "resolved") {
                // all ajax finished, execute code
            }
            $(_this).remove();
        });
    });
});
```

I'm not sure what the `$.automation` is for but I'll edit my answer if you needed it. Also, note how i use `.each()` to create a scope so that each element with class `signAlarm` is treated individually. You could create a global `prom` variable if you wanted all calls for all clickable elements to share.

Answer (score -1):

use `async` property of ajax.

> async (default: true) Type: Boolean
>
> By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests
>   and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.
>   Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser,
>   disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8,
>   the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you
>   must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the
>   corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done().

[refer this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'your url',
            global: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {},
            async: false, //set this false
            success: function() {}
        });
```

Comment: All calls are to be executed asynchronously  and are not dependant on eachother. I need to know if the browser is executing any ajax requests when I am in the success method of a current call. So when you click a button, you return to success method but before that the user managed to click a new button and start yet another ajax, in the first success method I want to know if any other ajax request are pending